# Module of smooth vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to show that the module of smooth vector fields is a free module over the ring of infinitely differentiable functions on some open subset of Euclidean space. I understand how to prove this from a differential geometry perspective; that is, using trivializing frames etc. However, is there a simple, purely algebraic approach here that I am missing?

Comment: There has to be some geometric input, because this is true if and only if the tangent bundle is trivial.